# does this integral proposition make any sense?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Someone told me that if $\int_{-1}^1f(x)g(x)dx=0, $ and $f,g$ are continuous, then $f(x)g(x)=0$ for all $x\in[-1,1]$.

Is this correct? I have failed to prove or disprove it.

Comment: Nope, try $x$. ${}{}{}$

Comment: Perhaps the conditions are not formulated correctly. If $f$ is a given continuous function, and that integral is zero for all continuous $g$, then I believe it **is** true that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in[-1,1]$. (All functions here are defined on $[-1,1]$.)

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not correct: try $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, this isn't true. Because the integral is over a symmetric domain, any odd $f(x)g(x)$ will integrate to zero.

For example, $f(x) = x, g(x) = 1$

Answer (score 0):

Think of what it would mean if it were true. Take $g(x) = 1$ and it would say that $\int_{-1}^1f(x)dx=0 \implies f(x) = 0$.  As Shanye2020 says, that would be true for any odd function.  Also, we could go on to prove that $\int_{a}^bf(x)dx=0 \implies f(x) = 0$ for any $a$ and $b$.